# Dictionary from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a long list of dictionaries like this

```
`SymbolInfo =
{
 "time":1602832092060,
 "data":[
   {"id": "a", "symbol": "Name1", "high": "1.1", "last": "1"}
   {"id": "b", "symbol": "Name2", "high": "2.2", "last": "2"}
   {"id": "c", "symbol": "Name3", "high": "3.3", "last": "3"} 
   ...]
}`
```

and I would like to obtain a dictionary of tuples with some specific values from that, like

`mydict = {'a': '1.1', 'b':'2.2', 'c':'3.3', ...}`

I was trying with a foor loop but since I am pretty new to python I would need to know how to write it correctly. Now I have:

```
`mydict = {}
 for x in symbolInfo:
    prices['data'][x]['a'] = float(['data'][x]['high'])`
```

but the error I get is "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Anyone can help me please? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need to loop over the list, not the dict containing it, so `for x in symbolInfo['data']: mydict[x['id']]=x['high']`

Answer (score 1):

This would get you the expected output you specified:

```py
mydict = {d["id"]: float(d["high"]) for d in SymbolInfo["data"]}
```

But I'm not sure if that's what you want. There is a lot of missing information in your post. What is `prices` variable? You said you wanted a dict of tuples as output, but the expected output you gave is just a normal dict?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to iterate all over the dict you only need Data key
so you can do it like that too:

```
Dict = {}
for x in SymbolInfo["data"]:
    Dict[x['id']]=x['high']
```